# recalculate latitude and longitude from a pixel in a cropped map

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, spherical-geometry

i want to recalculate a geographic coordinate from a pixel in a map.
For this i have the size and the coordinates from the map

to convert a coordinate to a pixel is use the algorithm, you find at https://gist.github.com/gagern/6636176

But how can i convert this back to the orginal geographic coordinate?

for the longitude i simply use

```
 Math.toDegrees((x+from.getLongitudeAsRad()*xFactor)/xFactor)
```

but how can i calculate the latitude?

best regards

Comment: While your tags are correct, the best topic is "map projections" (long,lat --> X,Y) and especially "_reverse_ (or inverse) map projections" (X,Y --> long,lat). You need to know _which_ projection. Please do more research. Good luck.

Comment: in addition to @martinf's comment, needing to know the map's coordinate system (projection) if the map image is available publicly that might help answerers as well.

Comment: hi, i found a solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103924/mercator-longitude-and-latitude-calculations-to-x-and-y-on-a-cropped-map-of-the/10401734#10401734 . thank you